# Destructing a string in Rust

Tags: rust

How can I do a complex pattern matching on a string? Something like this:

```
let res = match data.as_ref() {
    "aaa" => "this is aaa",
    "bbb" => "this is bbb ",
    //...........


    //aaa some_data_here
    "bbb {data2}" => &format!("this is 'bbb' + some data: {}", data2)

    x => &format!("this is not a pattern I know of, it is {}", x),
};
```

Comment: This looks like something a regex would solve although I am not entirely sure what your problem is.

Comment: What's in `data`? Could you add a [mcve]?

Comment: The simple answer is that you need to parse it, probably using a crate like [regex](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/index.html) with a compiled pattern for each matching case.

Comment: You can only `match` a type not a value.

Comment: @HenriMenke yes, you can match a (constant) value: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cae616bcd24976f393f6660d8b72c554&version=stable)

Comment: @PaoloFalabella, why constant in () ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing built-in in Rust, so you have to roll your own.

In simple cases you can use slices and helper methods like `starts_with()`, but if the patterns are more complex, try using regex or parser crates.

`match` supports "guards" that allow you to run extra code to refine a match:

```
match string {
  s if s.starts_with("bbb ") => format!("this is 'bbb' + some data: {}", &s[4..])
}
```